# Programa para buscar "palabras compatibles" no da resultado esperado

Tags: c++

estoy intentando realizar un programa para dado un entero no negativo d, y dos palabras, revise si son compatibles, que es si tienen la misma longitud y su distancia de Hamming es menor o igual que d. La distancia de Hamming de dos palabras de la misma longitud es el número de posiciones en las que difieren sus correspondientes letras.

La entrada comienza con un entero no negativo d. A continuación, un entero no negativo p seguido de una secuencia P de p palabras minúsculas. Finalmente, una secuencia S de palabras minúsculas seguida por la palabra "STOP" que indica su fin.

La salida es, para cada palabra de la secuencia S, la primera palabra de la secuencia P que es d-compatible con ella si existe, o el string "--" en caso contrario. Por ejemplo:

```
Input

0
3 mesa casa libro
mesa posa pesa pasa casa STOP

Output

mesa: mesa
posa: --
pesa: --
pasa: --
casa: casa
```

Cuando lo ejecuto solo se fija en la longitud de las palabras e imprime la primera que tiene la misma.

Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Pre: dues paraules minúscules; un enter no negatiu d
// Post: retorna true si les dues paraules són d-compatibles, false en cas contrari
bool d_compatibles(const string& a, const string b, int d) {
    int asize = a.size();

    if (a.size() == b.size()) {
        int dist, i;

        dist = i = 0;
        while (d <= dist and i < asize) {
            if (a[i] != b[i]) ++dist;
            ++i;
        }
        return d <= dist;
    }
    return false;
}

// Pre: un vector v de paraules minúscules; una paraula minúscula w; un enter no negatiu d
// Post: retorna la primera paraula a v d-compatible amb w; "--" en cas contrari
//v és P i w una paraula de S
string paraula_compatible(const vector<string>& v, const string& w, int d) {
    int i = 0;
    int vsize = v.size();
    while (i < vsize) {
        if (d_compatibles(v[i], w, d)) return v[i];
        ++i;
    }
    return "--";
}

int main() {
    int d, pn;
    cin >> d;
    cin >> pn;
    vector<string> P(pn);
    string w;
    for (int i = 0; i < pn; ++i) {
        cin >> P[i];
    }
    cin >> w;
    while (w != "STOP") {
        cout << w << ": " << paraula_compatible(P, w, d) << endl;
        cin >> w;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en la función `d_compatibles`, creo que has confundido `d` y `dist` en los chequeos.

Debería ser así:

```
bool d_compatibles(const string& a, const string b, int d) {
    int asize = a.size();
    if (a.size() == b.size()) {
        int dist, i;

        dist = i = 0;
        while (d >= dist and i < asize) {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
                ++dist;       
            
            ++i;
        }
        return d >= dist;
    }
    return false;
}
```